# Terminal prompt on new Mac is not the same as on my existing Mac

Tags: macos, zsh

```
MacOS Ventura 13.1
M2 Silicon
```

Trying to set up a new mac. On my existing Mac, I have a .zshrc, and in it, I have the following:

```
## begin Git branch prompt
git_branch_test_color() {
  local ref=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD 2> /dev/null)
  if [ -n "${ref}" ]; then
   if [ -n "$(git status --porcelain)" ]; then
     local gitstatuscolor='%F{red}'
   else
     local gitstatuscolor='%F{green}'
   fi
   echo "${gitstatuscolor} (${ref})"
 else
   echo ""
 fi
}
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
PROMPT='%/ $(git_branch_test_color)%F{none} $ '
# add 24h time the right side
RPROMPT='%D{%m-%d-%Y %k:%M:%S}'
## end Git branch prompt
```

And I would get something like:

```
/Users/jmac/Development/repos/p1  (development) $           02-16-2023 19:20:56
```

***(development) is in red***, because I have not checked in my changes and the full path is there for me to see.

On the new Mac, there is no .zshrc by default, so I added the code to the .zprofile file, and it's not working the same. I see the date/time on the right, but I don't see the full path and the prompt looks like this:

```
/Users/jmac p1 %           02-16-2023 19:20:56
```

Any ideas? prompt modification is not my forte.

Comment: Unrelated: you should upgrade to macOS 13.2.1, it fixes an [active exploit](https://www.macworld.com/article/1511385/macos-ventura-13-2-1-security-update-webkit.html).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: create a `~/.zshrc` file and move that code into it.

---

The slightly longer answer: something is overriding the value in the `PROMPT` variable. There isn't anything in the default `zsh` installation that'll turn the `$` in your prompt into a `%`.

That 'something' could be in a few different forms. There may be code that is modifying the `PS1` variable, which is essentially a synonym for `PROMPT`. Or there may be something hidden in scripts or functions called from `~/.zprofile` (for example, `oh-my-zsh` does this, albeit usually from `~/.zshrc`).

Some options

- Try to trace what's happening in the zprofile file. One way to do that is to run these commands:
  `setopt xtrace`
  `. ~/.zprofile`
  The main challenge here is often the sheer volume of the output; it may be difficult to find the spot where the prompt is being set.
- Move the `PROMPT` assignment to the bottom of `~/.zprofile`. Then your assignment should override whatever is setting the value earlier in the process.
- Move the `PROMPT` assignment into `~/.zshrc`. This is a better place for the assignment anyway, since .zshrc is only loaded for interactive shells, and setting the prompt is only used in interactive shells.
  The code in `~/.zshrc` is loaded after the code in `~/.zprofile`, so this has a similar effect to the prior option.

If none of these options have any effect, then you'll need to look for other startup files, e.g. `~/.zlogin`. There's a nice overview of how the various dot files are handled in `zsh` in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/388623).